# Is it possible to track real time metrics in a Spring boot Azure app?

Tags: azure, spring-boot

I have recently worked with Google Cloud App Engine, and there is the Google Cloud Monitoring app which allowed me to display in my webapp, passing through my server through a google client, metrics like percentage of cpu usage in a given timeframe, or number of cores.

Now I am working on Azure, and even though application insights gives me a whole huge number of metrics with micrometer, I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual data. From what ive read i can only setup new custom metrics to trak. Either that or im a moron that doesnt understand azure Documentation.

Is there a way to get that? Retrieve metric data like how many cores, or how much memory percentage. I know the metrics exists theoretically, but I cant figure out how to get them apart from the azure portal graphs, and i would like to get the graph points, so i can draw them in my website.

**Is that a thing?**

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but wouldn't spring boot actuator do exactly what you want? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: It might. I've read that page, but how do i bind it to azure? And how do i retrieve metrics. I cant find anything related

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bind it to azure" sorry dude. Actuator will give you a REST endpoint which will expose the metrics you're looking for. You then consume that endpoint somewhere.

Comment: Then how do i access that endpoint? and call some metrics?